# Is it possible to create a reducer with dynamic states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

React Application 16+, redux.

I have `bookRoom` component in `bookRoom.js` which is used to render single rectangle(which represents room) with number, as on the screenhot below.

**sample render**
[image: Screenshot]

This component is rendered with help of `map` in the parent `bookRooms.js` and `room` is passed as input property. I'd like to change the state of the room on rectangle click and I want to rerender only that particular component that I clicked.

**bookRoom.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import * as classes from './BookRoom.module.scss';
import './BookRoom.module.scss';

const bookRoom = function(room, setRooms, originalRoom) {
    if(!room.class) {
        room.class = classes.selected;
    }else if(room.class === classes.selected) {
        room.class = '';
    }
    originalRoom.class = room.class;
    setRooms({...room});
};

function BookRoom(props) {
    const [book, setBooks] = useState(props.book);
    const originalRoom = props.book;
    return (
        <div
             title={book.reservedBy ? `Booked by ${book.reservedBy}` : ''}
             className={`${classes.room} ${book.class || ''}`}
             onClick={bookRoom.bind(null, book, setBooks, originalRoom)}>
            <p>{book.bookId}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BookRoom;
```

**Sample usage of bookRoom**

```
<div className={classes.rooms}>
    {rooms.map((room, index) => (
        <BookRoom
            key={index}
            book={room}/>
     ))}
</div>
```

My current implementation uses `useState` hook, so the room is a private state of the component and when user clicked on it, only one rectangle will be updated. Also I am storing `originalBook` which points to room from the array, becase I need someway to update data in the parent component.

Now I want to use redux, and I'd like to create separate state per room. If amount of rooms is static I can do it, but rooms are fetched from the server and also it should be possible to remove some rooms from UI. I have this reducer:

```
export default combineReducers({
    rooms: roomsReducer,
    room: roomReducer
});
```

See the object passed to combineReducers, I'd like to know if can add/remove more states on the runtime, f.e. initially I have

```
export default combineReducers({
    rooms: roomsReducer
});
```

But after rooms fetched I'd like to see smth like this

```
export default combineReducers({
    rooms: roomsReducer
    room1: getRoomReducer(1),
    room2: getRoomReducer(2),
    room3: getRoomReducer(3)
});
```

So it will be valid to write

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        room: state['room' + props.roomId].rooms,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props) {
    return {
        book: () => dispatch({type: 'ROOM_CLICKED_'+props.bookId})
    }
}
```

So is it possible to modify root reducer on `rooms` state changed? To create separate state per room?

PS.Ideally get rid of keys as on the code without redux, but currently I have no ideas how to do this.

Comment: Why would you want 2 separate entities? You could store all information in the "rooms" state and identify in the redux reducer by key (id). `rooms: [ { id: 'room1', bookings: [] }, ... ]` 
and then just have one reducer that checks on id

Comment: @Tikkes I think if I update state with this `state = {...state, rooms: [...state.rooms]}` than all my single rooms components will be rerendered. Also I'd like to be able to reuse the single room component out of the array.

Comment: not if you have the same keys, which is what you should use for the key on your react component. So your `roomId` will be the key on your component

Comment: @Tikkes I have googled but fail to find how keys will help to update the element, I mean not the case, when I'am adding or removing elements, but when updating the element itself. Generally I see here many states: state of the array - length, elementOrder, etc. which can be managed by key , and the individual state of each element which is not managed by key and if I update this individual state I have to update all elements, but I was manage it previously with private state (without redux).

Comment: @Tikkes I now have an idea, I will try to keep private state, but when it updates I will update the global state without coping the properties, but not sure about rendering.

Comment: I don't think what you ask will be possible, since you are rendering an array and expect it to rerender on a single element change. React has no way of knowing whether or not just one of those has been changed, as far as I know anyway. updating the rootReducer will not be possible as per my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to just have one state with rooms.

Your reducer would just be one `roomsReducer`, if dynamically loaded it could look something like this:

```
export default function roomsReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ROOMS.SET:
            return setRooms(action.rooms);
        case types.ROOMS.BOOK:
            return bookRoom(state, action.data);
        default:
            return state || initialState.loadInitials().rooms;
    }
}
```

Then you update your room on `ROOMS.BOOK`

```
function bookRoom(state, data) {
    return [
        ...state.map(room=> {
            if (room.id !== data.id) {
                return room;
            } else {
                const newRoom = Object.assign({}, room);
                newRoom.booking = changeDataOnRoomBook() //fill this in
                return newRoom;
            }
        })
    ];
}
```

In your component then you can just fetch one room on your `mapStateToProps`

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const roomId = ownProps.id; //get room id from props
    const room = state.rooms
        ? state.rooms.find(room => {
                return room.id === roomId;
          })
        : null;

    return {
        room
    };
}
```